# Cannot balance eth0 IRQs across CPUs

Tags: linux, pci, interrupts, irq, affinity

I have servers which deal with a large number of network packets. I've seen evidence that user space processes running on CPU0 have their performance impacted when network load is high. I'm fairly sure this relates to  interrupt handling, specifically for network devices.

I'm thus experimenting with changing the affinity of network (eth) devices in order to test my hypothesis and see if I can improve performance.

I understand that in order to change IRQ affinity I must change the value in `/proc/irq/XXX/smp_affinity`.

When I change the value in that file I can only move the interrupt handling from one CPU to another. For example, in a 4 core system I can set that value to 1, 2, 4 or 8 and I see the interrupts move from cores 0,1,2 and 3 respectively (by monitoring `/proc/interrupts`). However, if I set the affinity value to any combination of cores then I don't see interrupts balanced across all cores. They always stick to one core. For example,

- Setting `ff`: CPU0 used
- Setting `12`: CPU4 used

(Thus it seems only the lowest specified core is used)

I have stopped the `irqbalance` daemon in case this was affecting things (although I suspect not as my understanding would be that `irqbalance` would change the values of the `smp_affinity` file and I don't see that).

My questions thus are:

- How do I balance interrupts across cores?
- Is it indeed even possible to do so?

N.B. I have tried this on 2 machines: A ubuntu VM running in VBox with 2 cores and with the eth device using `IO-APIC`; A ubuntu real machine with 4 cores (8 hyperthreaded) and with eth device using `PCI-MSI`.

As a bonus question:

- Is it possible to balance `PCI` interrupts? From what I understand it should be definitely possible with `IO-APIC` interrupts.

Comment: irqbalance certainly _should_ be doing this, if it's running.

Comment: If that's the case then it's possible I didn't see this when testing due to the load being too low for irqbalance to see it as a problem. Is that feasible in a low load situation? But regardless, the type of control I'm looking at would be to manually control the affinity. So I'd really like to understand whether the builtin OS functionality `/proc/irq/XXX/smp_affinity` should work and if so why it doesn't.

Comment: did you ever figure out the solution?

Comment: Afraid not. As with all things like this, never found a solution, project moved on, never came back to it ('_')